# how can I have a teammate restart heroku server from his machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, heroku

I have a rails app up on heroku.  Sometimes the server bombs out and I have to go to the console and execute `heroku restart` so that servers get restarted.  This seems to fix the problem.
However, I am not on my machine all the time.  I would like to have a team member have this capability as well.

For this to happen...what does he need to do? Does he need to first have access to the github repository so that he can push and pull code to the repository and then install heroku on his machine?

Can this be done without git hub? can he just install heroku?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

He needs the Heroku gem (`$ sudo gem install heroku`).  He needs a SSH key, and a Heroku account that takes the key (`$ heroku keys:add (pathToKey)`).  He needs to have his account added to the Heroku project as a collaborator.  And then it’s all fine, he could say `$ heroku restart --app (appName)`.

Comment: once he has an account and adds ssh key to it...how do I add him as a collaborator to the heroku project?

Comment: You’ll go to your app’s general information page:

    https://api.heroku.com/myapps/YOUR_APP_NAME

and add him there.

Comment: is it possible to automate this whole process ?